# Is there a way to hide a button on every page except Home page of a site in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

```
<div class="page-header">
             {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <a href="{% url 'post_new' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
             {% endif %}
             <h1><a href="/">Django Girls Blog</a></h1>
             {% if user.is_anonymous %}
             <h4><a href="/login">LogIn</a></h4>
             {% endif %}
             {% if user.is_authenticated %}
              <a href="{% url 'post_draft_list' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
             {% endif %}
             {% if user.is_authenticated %}
             <h3><a href="/user">{{ user }}</a></h3>
             <h4><a href="/logout">LogOut></a></h4>
             {% endif %}
```

Comment: Just put that code on the home page only.

Comment: You can add `show_button` to the `context` dictionary in the home page view, then in the template do something like `{% if show_button %}Button{% endif %}`. If you need more help, please show your view for the homepage, and say which button you want to hide.

Comment: @SergeyPugach I have my home page set as base.html for all other pages, so it reflects on every page I have.

Comment: You can have a homepage.html with your logic with extending base.html

Comment: @SergeyPugach yeah that can be one of those choices, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. Check if the current page is the home page and if it is not then hide the button with css. Like so:

```
<button {% if request.path != '/' %} style="display: none;" {% endif %}>My Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the navbar I used this and it worked. The code below shows a button named "Create" on home page only:

```
{% if request.resolver_match.url_name == 'home' %}
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" href={% url enter code here'create' %}> Create </a>
{% endif %}
```